# Running a python script on all the files in a directory

Tags: python, command-line, scripting

I have a Python script that reads through a text csv file and creates a playlist file. However I can only do one at a time, like:

```
python playlist.py foo.csv foolist.txt
```

However, I have a directory of files that need to be made into a playlist, with different names, and sometimes a different number of files.

So far I have looked at creating a txt file with a list of all the names of the file in the directory, then loop through each line of that, however I know there must be an easier way to do it.

Comment: *and some times there are more than overs* what does it mean?

Comment: @davr; why'd you remove the bash tag, maybe he wants to use it?

Comment: Sorry I had the bash tag, as I was trying to do it through bash, as eventually I want to put a cocoa front end for bash.

The cheap hack I used from reading from text files was in bash too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for f in *.csv; do
  python playlist.py "$f" "${f%.csv}list.txt"
done
```

Will that do the trick? This will put foo.csv in foolist.txt and abc.csv in abclist.txt.

Or do you want them all in the same file?

Answer (score 6):

Just use a for loop with the asterisk glob, making sure you quote things appropriately for spaces in filenames

```
for file in *.csv; do
   python playlist.py "$file" >> outputfile.txt;
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it a single directory, or nested?

Ex.

```
topfile.csv
topdir
   --dir1
       --file1.csv
       --file2.txt
       --dir2
           --file3.csv
           --file4.csv
```

For nested, you can use `os.walk(topdir)` to get all the files and dirs recursively within a directory.

You could set up your script to accept dirs or files:

`python playlist.py topfile.csv topdir`

```
import sys
import os

def main():
    files_toprocess = set()
    paths = sys.argv[1:]
    for p in paths:
        if os.path.isfile(p) and p.endswith('.csv'):
            files_toprocess.add(p)
        elif os.path.isdir(p):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
                files_toprocess.update([os.path.join(root, f) 
                                        for f in files if f.endswith('.csv')])
```

Comment: I'll give this a try too thanks, it's a bit temperamental the script as it is

Answer (score 2):

if you have directory name you can use [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)

```
os.listdir(dirname)
```

if you want to select only a certain type of file, e.g., only csv file you could use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module.

Comment: or just use '.' as directory name?