# open file in Python using "python scriptname.py filename"

Tags: python, file-io

I am a novice to python scripting. I have a script that I am hoping to run on all files in a directory. I found very helpful advice in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609159/running-a-python-script-on-all-the-files-in-a-directory). However, I am having difficulty in determining how to format the actual script so that it retrieves the filename of the file that I want to run the script on in the command prompt, i.e. "python script.py filename.*" I've tried my best at looking through the Python documentation and the forums in this site and have come up empty (I probably just don't know what keywords I should be searching).

I am currently able to run my script on one file at a time, and output it with a new file extension using the following code, but this way I can only do one file at a time. I'd like to be able to iterate over the whole directory using 'GENE.*':

```
InFileName = 'GENE.303'

InFile = open(InFileName, 'r') #opens a pipeline to the file to be read line by line

OutFileName = InFile + '.phy'

OutFile = open(OutFileName, 'w')
```

What can I do to the code to allow myself to use an iteration through the directory similar to what is done in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609159/running-a-python-script-on-all-the-files-in-a-directory)? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
import sys
InFileName = sys.argv[1]
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

For something more sophisticated, take a look at the `optparse` and `argparse` modules (the latter is preferable but is only available in newer versions of Python).

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options to process a list of files using Python:

---

You can use the shell expansion facilities of your command line to pass more filenames to your script and then iterate the [command line arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):

```
import sys

def process_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            # TODO: implement
            print line

for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
    process_file(fname)
```

and call it like:

```
python my_script.py * # expands to all files in the directory
```

---

You can also use the [glob module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to do this expansion:

```
import glob

for fname in glob.glob('*'):
    process_file(fname)
```